# Gradle PMD plugin *sometimes* fails to find SAXParserFactoryImpl

Tags: gradle, pmd

When running a gradle build with the PMD plugin on, this happens sometimes, but not always.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':subproject:pmd'.
> Could not resolve net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd:5.0.2.
  Required by:
      XYZ:subproject:1.0b5.3625
   > Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
   > Could not resolve org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:7.
      > Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
      > Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
```

I don't know how to progress this transient issue. Any clues?

Comment: What is Gradle version you use?

Comment: Gradle 1.5-rc2 & Java 7. Appears on Windows and RedHat.